# Get number of questions by tag name

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, questions, api

I am just curious to know whether there is a way to find out which tag has got most number of questions on a day.

Like at the moment, i see 582,073 questions overall for [**java**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, 531,473 questions for [**php**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag, 463,630 questions for [**android**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag and 598,189 questions for [**C#**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#)

So can i know how many questions are being asked today on Java/C#/PHP?
Hope there exists any API to filter that data, instead of manually visiting that tag page and counting them.

Comment: I think android tag has most number of question at present.

Comment: @Kedarnath Well, included that in question. But how to calculate that without counting manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for a general location to see how many questions have been asked today, you can take a look at the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), which shows all of the tags on different pages. Unfortunately you can't sort by the number of questions asked today, nor is the data directly available from there. I don't know if there's an API method that does what you want, but if you're just looking for something from the user interface that would do.